# Error in Async pipe while using autocomplete

Tags: html, angular

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
<input type="text" matInput class="formControl" [formControl]="name" 
[matAutocomplete]="auto" >
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of city | async" [value]="option" >
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Typescript

```
stores:locators;
city:string[]=[];
ngOnInit(){
this.service.getStores()
.subscribe(data=>{
    this.stores=data,
    this.length=this.stores.length,
    console.log("length"+this.length)
    for(let i=0;i<this.length;i++)
    {
      this.city.push(this.stores[i].city)
    }
    console.log(this.city)
   }
)

}
```

Interface

```
export interface locators{
  "city":string
  "places":Array<{}>
}
```

Error:

> Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
>   at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:4232)

Not able to populate autocomplete values, even city is an array of strings?

Comment: The [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) is meant to be used with an Observable or Promise. Not an array.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that `city` is loaded asynchronously. But since it is an array, you don't have to wait for that to load in your `ngFor`. Because `ngFor` will never loop since it has no data. So you wont get any errors for looping through `asynchronously loaded array data`.

Only if you were accessing the length of an array, somewhere like `city.length`, then you should be using safe navigation operator (?.) which will wait for the asynchronous data to load.

`{{city?.length}}`

In your code you donot need the `async` pipe

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of city" [value]="option" >
      {{option}}
</mat-option>
```